# OpenCV HSV Parsing Issue (C++)

Tags: c++, opencv, colors, hsv

First of all, I realize there are existing questions about converting an RGB image to an HSV image out there; I used one of those questions to help me write my code.  However, I am getting values for HSV that don't make sense to me.

What I know about HSV I have gotten from [this website](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/colortheory/web/hsv.html).  From [this colorpicker](http://colorizer.org/), I have inferred that H is a number ranging from 0-360 degrees, S is a number ranging from 0-100%, and V is a number ranging from 0-100%.  Therefore, I had assumed that my code (as follows) would return an H value between 0 and 360, and S/V values between 0 and 100.  However, this is not the case.

I plugged my program's output into the above color picker, which all S/V values down to 100 when they exceeded 100.  As you can see, the output is *close* to what it should be, but is not accurate.  I feel like this is because I am interpreting the HSV values incorrectly.

For contex, I am going to establish a range for each color on the cube and from there look at the other faces and fill out the current setup of the cube in another program I have.

My code:

```
void get_color(Mat img, int x_offset, int y_offset) 
{
    Rect outline(x_offset - 2, y_offset - 2, 5, 5);
    rectangle(img, outline, Scalar(255, 0, 0), 2);

    Rect sample(x_offset, y_offset, 1, 1);
    Mat rgb_image = img(sample);
    Mat hsv_image;
    cvtColor(rgb_image, hsv_image, CV_BGR2HSV);

    Vec3b hsv = hsv_image.at<Vec3b>(0, 0);
    int hue = hsv.val[0]; 
    int saturation = hsv.val[1];
    int value = hsv.val[2];

    printf("H: %d, S: %d, V: %d \n", hue, saturation, value);
}
```

Output of the program:

```
H: 21, S: 120, V: 191 // top left cubie
H: 1, S: 180, V: 159  // top center cubie
H: 150, S: 2, V: 142  // top right cubie
H: 86, S: 11, V: 159  // middle left cubie
H: 75, S: 12, V: 133  // middle center cubie
H: 5, S: 182, V: 233  // middle right cubie
H: 68, S: 7, V: 156   // bottom left cubie
H: 25, S: 102, V: 137 // bottom center cubie
H: 107, S: 155, V: 69 // bottom right cubie
```

Starting image (pixel being extracted @ center of each blue square):

[image]

Resulting colors (as the above color picker gave):

[image]

As you can see, the red and white is fairly accurate, but the orange and yellow are not correct and the blue is blatantly wrong; it is impossible for the pixel I looked at to actually be that color.  What am I doing wrong?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: unsigned byte (Vec3b) can't represent values between 0 and 360, that's why openCV reduces the hue resolution by half and uses values from 0 to 180 by default  S and V channels are 0..255 . there is a special flag that uses 0..255 on hue channel that are scaled from 0..360 (some more resolution than 0..180) but default is 0..180

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV has a funny way of representing its colors.

**Hue** - Represented as a number from 0-179 instead of 0-360.  Therefore, multiply the H value by two before plugging it into a traditional color picker.

**Saturation/Value** - Represented as a number from 0-255.  To get a percentage, divide given answer by 255 and multiply by 100 to get a percentage.

Everything works much more sensibly now. See [this website](http://www.shervinemami.info/colorConversion.html) for more details on OpenCV and HSV.

Comment: "funny" means "efficient" here: 360 just doesn't fit in an unsigned byte ;)